# Axis labels doesn't show up seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am ptrying to plot using following code, but axis labels doesn't show up.

```
 g = sns.lmplot(x='ANR', y='ANR_mean', data=new_df_L) 

def annotate(data, **kws):
    slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = scipy.stats.linregress(data['ANR_mean'], data['ANR'])
    print(rvalue, pvalue)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(.02, .9, 'r2={:.2f}, p={:.2g}'.format(rvalue**2, pvalue),
            transform=ax.transAxes)
g.set_axis_labels( "ANR Estimated" , "ANR Observed" )
 
g.map_dataframe(annotate)

plt.show()
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How about changing the execution order of `g.set_axis_labels( "ANR Estimated" , "ANR Observed" )`? You could put it inside a function or before plt.show().

Comment: thank you @r-beginners. it solved.